# Trouble with running function before FileReader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I've got some code running within a Vue.js component, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I just want to run `loadingAnimation()` before the filereading, but searching on the internet for this error didn't really help me. What is the best way of doing this?

This is my code:

```
openFileBrowse() {
      var vm = this;
      var input = document.getElementById("filebutton");
      if (input.files[0].type != "application/vnd.ms-excel"){
      alert("You have uploaded a wrong file type. We require a .csv file not a " + input.files[0].type + " file.");
      } else {
        //Update loader text
        vm.updateLoader('parsing csv');

        //Start loadscreen
        vm.loadingAnimation().then(function () {
          //Start reading data
          var reader = new FileReader();
          var csvData = "";
          var jsonData;
          var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
          reader.onload = function(){
            csvData = iconv.decode(reader.result, 'latin1');
            jsonData = vm.tsvJSON(csvData);
            vm.addFiles(jsonData);
          };
          reader.onloadend = function(){
            //Go to visualization page
            router.push({ name: 'Visualization' });
          };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
        });
      }
    },
    loadingAnimation() {
      //Make loading screen visible with animation
      var target = document.getElementById('loadBox');
      target.classList.remove('hidden')
      setTimeout(function () {
      target.classList.remove('visuallyhidden');
      }, 20);
    }
```

Comment: Why is that surprising? `loadingAnimation` *doesn't* return anything, certainly not a promise.

Comment: Well @jonrsharpe I'm not that experienced with JavaScript, so promises aren't familiar with me. I'm just trying to find a way to run loadingAnimation before the filereading, because without this .then, the loadingAnimation() method doesn't even run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadingAnimation` isn't an `async` function and doesn't explicitly return a promise, so calling it doesn't give you a promise. In fact, it doesn't have *any* explicit return value, so calling it will always give you `undefined`.

If you want it to return a promise that will be fulfilled when the timer callback is fired, you have to code it. For instance:

```
loadingAnimation() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    //Make loading screen visible with animation
    var target = document.getElementById('loadBox');
    target.classList.remove('hidden')
    setTimeout(function () {
      target.classList.remove('visuallyhidden');
      resolve();
    }, 20);
  });
}
```